# How to pass mock date event value on unit testing in angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a function which needs date from datepicker event. I used matdatepicker to select date from UI.

**i want to pass date event value on onDateSelected() function.**

can anybody help me to pass date event value to pass my unit test case.

i tried below code but it wont works

**my function**

```
 onDateSelected(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
    const dts = event.value;
    const startDate = moment(dts).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    this.details.controls.contractStartDate.setValue(startDate);
    this.selectedDate = this.details.get('contractStartDate').value;
    this.selectedDate = event.value;
  }
```

**Unit testing code**

```
  it('should check ondate selected event', () => {
    const date = new Date(10/03/2019);
    component.onDateSelected(date);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.details.get('contractStartDate').value.toString()).toEqual(date);
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

```
const date: any = { value : new Date(10/03/2019) };
```

Just look at how you write your function, and follow the object properties.

Comment: but it shows error when i am passing date to component.onDateSelected(date); function 
  error is Argument of type '{ value: Date; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>'.
  Type '{ value: Date; }' is missing the following properties from type 'MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>': target, targetElement

Comment: @Sai typing error, edited my answer to resolve that

Comment: use of any makes it possible to bypass type in the method.. great it works..!